# Restservice with curl simpleget not working

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, rest, curl

I'm trying to use my webservice by curl:

```
    public function getImages($time) {
        $url = $this->rest_url['employees'] . "?action=getAllNewPhotos&accessKey=" . $this->rest_key['employees'] . "&lastcheck=" . $time;

        $data = $this->CI->curl->simple_get($url);

        if ($data) {
            return json_decode($data);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function simple_get() on a non-object

Why is that?

Also if I add curl in my autoload it says:

> Unable to load the requested class: curl

However if I run my code by following code, there is no problem:

```
        $url = $this->rest_url['employees'] . "?action=getAllNewPhotos&accessKey=" . $this->rest_key['employees'] . "&lastcheck=" . $time;
         $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($data) {
            return json_decode($data);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

I'm just curious why my first approach is not working!

If you need more clarification, please let me knwo!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing a few things.

If you want to load this as a Codeigniter library, you need to first create it as one. Steps are found in the User Guide. This will go in your libraries directory.

simple_get() should then be a function on your class library called "curl". However, I would probably use a different name to avoid naming clashes

Comment: Thanks so much, could you please let me know where I can find the steps? I could nt find it in user guide!, and thanks so much for clarification :)

Comment: The call them libraries, not custom classes, so in here is everything you need: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html